# What are the guidelines for using numba for a tree structure?

Tags: python, data-structures, numba

Edit: Forgot to run numba more than once (oops!)

Ive looked at the numba versions of namedtuple and Dict as potential solutions but they seem much slower (about 10000x slower) in comparison to their python counterparts.

```
import time
from numba import njit
from collections import namedtuple    

Alpha = namedtuple("Alpha", ["a", "b", "c"])    
Regions = namedtuple("Regions", ["a", "b"])    
State = namedtuple("State", ["H", "L"])    
Parameters = namedtuple("Parameters", ["alpha", "DB", "beta", "psi", "pi", "CC_opt"])    

def timer_func(func):
    def function_timer(*args, **kwargs):    
        start = time.time()    
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)    
        end = time.time()    
        runtime = end - start    
        msg = "{func} took {time} seconds to complete its execution."    
        print(msg.format(func=func.__name__, time=runtime))    
        return value    

    return function_timer    


@timer_func    
def build_params() -> Parameters:    
    alpha = Regions(    
        a=Alpha(0.5, 0.5, 0),    
        b=Alpha(0.5, 0.5, 0),    
    )    

    return Parameters(alpha=alpha, DB=State(0.0, 0.0), beta=0.8, psi=0.0, pi=0.5, CC_opt=1.0)    


@timer_func    
@njit    
def build_params_numba() -> Parameters:    
    alpha = Regions(    
        a=Alpha(0.5, 0.5, 0),    
        b=Alpha(0.5, 0.5, 0),    
    )    

    return Parameters(alpha=alpha, DB=State(0.0, 0.0), beta=0.8, psi=0.0, pi=0.5, CC_opt=1.0)    


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    build_params()    
    build_params_numba()
```

build_params took 3.814697265625e-06 seconds to complete its execution.

build_params_numba took 0.07473492622375488 seconds to complete its execution.

Edit:

build_params_numba took 3.5762786865234375e-06 seconds to complete its execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue is the fact that you are measuring the first execution of `build_params_numba`, which includes the compilation (it is compiled Just-In-Time, just as you requested). This is like measuring the time-to-dinner between a classic meal and a microwave meal, but you're including the time to buy and install a microwave oven as part of the latter. [Measure the *second* invocation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#how-to-measure-the-performance-of-numba) of `build_params_numba`, when the compilation has been already completed, to see how the compiled function performs.

The second issue is that `numba` might not be of much help with your code. AFAIK it is designed to speed up numerical algorithms and numpy code. By necessity, `namedtuple` and `dict` are Python data structures and `numba` has to treat them as such; so even though you requested [nopython](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode) mode, Numba cannot oblige, as it only works when a native data type can be detected for all values in your code (I think — not 100% sure on this point though).

Comment: first is a fair point (completely forgot to add XD), and in the second iteration the speed is indistinguishable.

For the second point, I have lots of other functions that use numba that will build new instances of params and then use a number of numerical algos. Once numba compiles the function, will that function still be fast even when called in multiprocessing or will it need to be recompiled for each core?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Test and it should be obvious, the difference is pretty striking :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you the points for now unless/until someone else has a better way of thinking about trees in numba!